# Give access to ec2 AWS user only to specific files

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to amazon using aws and an user that I created in ec2. Unfortunately, I can't connect in filezilla to that user using the key, only to the default aws user. How exactly should I go about this?

Comment: whats your IAM policies for this user ? has it been added to specific group with given right on ec2 ?

Comment: When you create a new user, you will also need to add the public key to the authorized key set.  have you followed the steps mentioned in the following article http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html.

Comment: You will need to create a jailed user in that EC2 instance and generate a key for that user.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you saying that you are trying to FTP to an Amazon EC2 instance? Where was the "user" defined -- was it on the EC2 instance, or is it an AWS user defined in Identity and Access Management (IAM)? Can you provide more details of what you did and what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a user on ec2 with a command like `adduser` then to use this new user with filezilla set a password for the user with the `passwd` command.  Then use the same username/password combination from filezilla

To use filezilla with ssh key pairs

- generate a new key pair for the new user with the `ssh-keygen` command.
- Put the public part in the new user's .ssh/authorized_keys file.
- Ensure that the authorized_keys has the correct permissions and owner.
- Convert the private key to pem or ppk format and load it into filezilla

See https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto